# Distribution of the difference between the maximum of $n$ identical and correlated Gaussian random variables and any one of them

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, extreme-value

Suppose, there are $n$ identical and correlated Gaussian random variables namely, $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ with $X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ for all $i\in\{1,2, ...n\}$. The correlation coefficient between any two of them is upper bounded by a value $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$, i.e., $\rho_{i,j}\le\varepsilon, \forall i\ne j; i,j\in[n]$.

Is there any known parametric distribution characterizing the difference between maximum of them and any one of them. I other words, I am looking for the distribution of random variable $Z=X_{max}-X_i$.
Actually, my final goal is to find a non-trival upper bound of $\text{Pr}[Z\le\tau]$ as a function of $\tau$. Hence, if you are aware of such bound, please refer to me here.

Comment: Are you asking for the name of the distribution (assuming it has one) or just what the formula for the distribution is?

Comment: This distribution has an atom at $0$ with weight $1/n$, hence would not be a standard distribution.

Comment: How the atom at $0$ weights $1/n$? How it implies that it's not a standard distribution? I am not familiar with this concept. Can you please clarify or give some reference? @Xi'an

Comment: Actually, I am looking for the bound I mentioned in the question. Even if there is no known distribution, it'll be fine as long as I can find a way to calculate the bound. @jibowman

Comment: The weight is not necessarily $1/n,$ but there definitely is an atom at $0,$ because the chance that $Z=0$ is the chance that $X_i=X_{\max}$ and that chance obviously is nonzero for at least one $i$ (and, in fact, is nonzero for all $i$). At best, then, the distribution would be a mixture of an atom and a known continuous distribution.  Are you supposing "the correlation coefficient between any two of them" is *the same* in every case? If so, the weight of this atom must be $1/n$ by exchangeability.

Comment: No, the correlation coefficients can be different for different pairs, but there is a bound for them (i.e., $\rho_{i,j}\le\varepsilon$). I get your idea that the distribution is the mixture of an atom and a known distribution. But what is the known distribution in that case? Is it half-gaussian distribution? @whuber

Comment: It will not generally have any simple expression.  It can always be expressed conditional on which of the $X_i$ is largest, which makes it a finite mixture of distributions.  I think a bound would have to be obtained less directly, without finding the distribution of $Z$ itself.